# Why do some cells not move entirely

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have set up this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/386er/dhzq6q6f/14/

```
var moveCell = function(direction) {

var cellToBeMoved = pickRandomCell();
var currentX = cellToBeMoved.x.baseVal.value; 
var currentY = cellToBeMoved.y.baseVal.value;
var change = getPlusOrMinus() * (cellSize + 1 );
var newX = currentX + change;
var newY = currentY + change;
var selectedCell = d3.select(cellToBeMoved);


if (direction === 'x') {
    selectedCell.transition().duration(1500)
        .attr('x', newX );
} else {
    selectedCell.transition().duration(1500)
        .attr('y', newY );

}
```

}

In the moveCell function, I pick a random cell, request its current x and y coordinates and then add or subtract its width or height, to move it to an adjacent cell.

What I am wondering about: If you watch the cells move, some will only move partially to the next cell. Can anoyne tell me, why this is so ?

Comment: This is pretty cool, mate. but sorry. no idea why some cells aren't moving fully. someone will. I have found that the issue becomes much more obvious based upon changing the height, width and cell size; I think this may be the cause. http://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/dhzq6q6f/15/

Comment: I just tried removing the transition and it works fine. Just a step in the right direction.

Comment: Ahh, I think it's because cells are randomly selected that are already moving. Try adding a flag to transitioning cells and excluding those in `pickRandomCell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do in this situation is put `.each("interrupt", function() { console.log("interrupted!") });` on your transitions.  Then you will see the problem.
Its supposed to fix it if you name the transitions like `selection.transition("name")`, but that doesn't fix it.
That means you have to do as suggested by @jcuenod and exclude the ones that are moving.  One way to do that which is idiomatic is like this...

```
if (direction === 'x') {
    selectedCell.transition("x").duration(1500)
      .attr('x', newX)
      .each("start", function () { lock.call(this, "lockedX") })
      .each("end", function () { unlock.call(this, "lockedX") });
} else {
    selectedCell.transition("y").duration(1500)
      .attr('y', newY)
      .each("start", function () { lock.call(this, "lockedX") })
      .each("end", function () { unlock.call(this, "lockedX") });
}

function lock(lockClass) {
    var c = { cell: false }; c[lockClass] = true;
    d3.select(this).classed(c)
};
function unlock(lockClass) {
    var c = { cell: this.classList.length == 1 }; c[lockClass] = false;
    d3.select(this).classed(c);
};
```

[Here](//jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/kh0x28dL/3/) is a fiddle to prove the concept.

---

### **Pure and idiomatic d3 version**

Just for completeness here is the d3 way to do it.
I've tried to make it as idiomatic as possible.  The main points being...

1. **Purely data-driven**
   The data is updated and the viz manipulation left entirely to d3 declarations.
2. **Use d3 to detect and act on changes to svg element *attributes***
   This is done by using a composite `key` function in the `selection.data()` method and by exploiting the fact that changed nodes (squares where the `x`, `y` or `fill`attributes don't match the updated data) are captured by the exit selection.
3. **Splice changed elements into the data array so d3 can detect changes**
   Since a *reference* to the data array elements is bound to the DOM elements, any change to the data will also be reflected in the `selection.datum()`.  d3 uses a `key` function to compare the data values to the `datum`, in order to classify nodes as update, enter or exit.  If a `key` is made, that is a function of the data/datum values, changes to data will not be detected.  By `splice`-ing changes into the data array, the value referenced by `selection.datum()` will be different from the data array, so data changes will flag exit nodes.
   By simply manipulating attributes and putting transitions on the exit selection and not removing it, it essentially becomes a 'changed' selection.
   this only works if the data values are objects.
4. **Concurrent transitions**
   Named transitions are used to ensure x and y transitions don't interrupt each other, but it was also necessary to use tag class attributes to lock out transitioning elements.  This is done using transition start and end events.
5. **Animation frames**
   `d3.timer` is used to smooth animation and marshal resources.  d3Timer calls back to update the data before the transitions are updated, before each animation frame.
6. **Use `d3.scale.ordinal()` to manage positioning**
   This is great because you it works every time and you don't even have to thin about it.

---

```js
$(function () {
 var container,
  svg,
  gridHeight = 800,
  gridWidth = 1600,
  cellSize, cellPitch,
  cellsColumns = 100,
  cellsRows = 50,
  squares,

  container = d3.select('.svg-container'),
  svg = container.append('svg')
   .attr('width', gridWidth)
   .attr('height', gridHeight)
   .style({ 'background-color': 'black', opacity: 1 }),

  createRandomRGB = function () {
   var red = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)).toString(),
     green = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)).toString(),
     blue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)).toString(),
     rgb = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
   return rgb;
  },

  createGrid = function (width, height) {

   var scaleHorizontal = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(cellsColumns))
      .rangeBands([0, width], 1 / 15),
     rangeHorizontal = scaleHorizontal.range(),

     scaleVertical = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(cellsRows))
      .rangeBands([0, height]),
     rangeVertical = scaleVertical.range(),

     squares = [];
   rangeHorizontal.forEach(function (dh, i) {
    rangeVertical.forEach(function (dv, j) {
     var indx;
     squares[indx = i + j * cellsColumns] = { x: dh, y: dv, c: createRandomRGB(), indx: indx }
    })
   });

   cellSize = scaleHorizontal.rangeBand();
   cellPitch = {
    x: rangeHorizontal[1] - rangeHorizontal[0],
    y: rangeVertical[1] - rangeVertical[0]
   }

   svg.selectAll("rect").data(squares, function (d, i) { return d.indx })
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'cell')
    .attr('width', cellSize)
    .attr('height', cellSize)
    .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y })
    .style('fill', function (d) { return d.c });

   return squares;
  },

  choseRandom = function (options) {
   options = options || [true, false];
   var max = options.length;
   return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * (max))];
  },

  pickRandomCell = function (cells) {

    var l = cells.size(),
      r = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);

    return l ? d3.select(cells[0][r]).datum().indx : -1;

  };

 function lock(lockClass) {
  var c = { cell: false }; c[lockClass] = true;
  d3.select(this).classed(c)
 };
 function unlock(lockClass) {
  var c = { cell: this.classList.length == 1 }; c[lockClass] = false;
  d3.select(this).classed(c);
 };

 function permutateColours() {
  var samples = Math.min(50, Math.max(~~(squares.length / 50),1)), s, ii = [], i, k = 0,
    cells = d3.selectAll('.cell');
  while (samples--) {
   do i = pickRandomCell(cells); while (ii.indexOf(i) > -1 && k++ < 5 && i > -1);
   if (k < 10 && i > -1) {
    ii.push(i);
    s = squares[i];
    squares.splice(i, 1, { x: s.x, y: s.y, c: createRandomRGB(), indx: s.indx });
   }
  }

 }

 function permutatePositions() {
  var samples = Math.min(20, Math.max(~~(squares.length / 100),1)), s, ss = [], d, m, p, k = 0,
    cells = d3.selectAll('.cell');
  while (samples--) {
   do s = pickRandomCell(cells); while (ss.indexOf(s) > -1 && k++ < 5 && s > -1);
   if (k < 10 && s > -1) {
    ss.push(s);
    d = squares[s];
    m = { x: d.x, y: d.y, c: d.c, indx: d.indx };
    m[p = choseRandom(["x", "y"])] = m[p] + choseRandom([-1, 1]) * cellPitch[p];

    squares.splice(s, 1, m);
   }
  }
 }

 function updateSquares() {
        //use a composite key function to transform the exit selection into
        // an attribute update selection
        //because it's the exit selection, d3 doesn't bind the new data
        // that's done manually with the .each 
  var changes = svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(squares, function (d, i) { return d.indx + "_" + d.x + "_" + d.y + "_" + d.c; })
   .exit().each(function (d, i, j) { d3.select(this).datum(squares[i]) })

  changes.transition("x").duration(1500)
   .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x })
   .each("start", function () { lock.call(this, "lockedX") })
   .each("end", function () { unlock.call(this, "lockedX") })

  changes.transition("y").duration(1500)
   .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y })
   .each("start", function () { lock.call(this, "lockedY") })
   .each("end", function () { unlock.call(this, "lockedY") });

  changes.attr("stroke", "white")
   .style("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
   .transition("fill").duration(800)
    .style('fill', function (d, i) { return d.c })
    .style("stroke-opacity", 0)
    .each("start", function () { lock.call(this, "lockedFill") })
    .each("end", function () { unlock.call(this, "lockedFill") });
 }
 squares = createGrid(gridWidth, gridHeight);

 d3.timer(function tick() {
  permutateColours();
  permutatePositions();
  updateSquares();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <div class="svg-container"></div>
```

> NOTE: requires d3 version 3.5.5 for the position transitions to run.

**EDIT:** fixed a problem with lock and un-lock.  Would probably better to tag the data rather than write classes to the DOM but, anyway... this way is fun.

Comment: Man you made my day!  Thank you so much! I will go through your code examples thoroughly.

Comment: No drama, I can't stop staring at the thing... The animation runs twice as fast if you store the locked status on the nodes' `datum()`, instead of writing to the DOM with `classed`, but you have to manage multiple locks and only *un*lock after all transitions are complete. This is easily managed by using a `d3.map()` as the locks list for each node.

Comment: Actually, make that 30% faster... I got a bit over-excited. :p